# I am inserting data in database. Image is uploading but data is not saving?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, insert

The code is given as i am trying to insert data into database after uploading image but it is not storing. I don't know why??

```
public partial class upload : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void UploadVideo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string constr = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-1VOSUKD\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Youtube;Integrated Security=True";
        if (VideoUpload.PostedFile != null && ThumbnailUpload.PostedFile!=null)
        {

            //Video
            string user = Session["user"].ToString();
            string videoname = Path.GetFileName(VideoUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
            string vid = user + "-video-" + videoname.Split('.')[0].ToString();
            string ext = videoname.Split('.')[1];
            string pathServer = Server.MapPath("~\\uservideos\\" + vid + "." + ext);
            VideoUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(pathServer);
            string pathAccess = "~/uservideos/" + vid + "." + ext;
            string time = "";
            //Thumbnail

            string thumbname = Path.GetFileName(ThumbnailUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
            string thumb = user + "-thumbnail-"+videoname+"-" + thumbname.Split('.')[0].ToString();
            string thumbext = thumbname.Split('.')[1];
            string thumbpathServer = Server.MapPath("~\\thumbnails\\" + thumb + "." + thumbext);
            ThumbnailUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(thumbpathServer);
            string thumbpathAccess = "~/thumbnails/" + thumb + "." + thumbext;

            //add to database
            try
            {                                        
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
                con.Open();

                string q = "insert into videos(Upload_User, Title, Discription, Video_Time, Tags, [Format], Thumbnail_Path, Video_Path) " +
                    "values('" + user + "','" + Title.Text + "','" + DiscriptionTextBox.Text + "','" + time + "','" + TagsTextBox.Text + "','" + ext + "','" + pathAccess + "','" + thumbpathAccess + "')";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Data Saved!');</script>");
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception exe)
            {
                Response.Write("<script> alert('"+exe.Message+"');</script>");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you catch any exceptions?

Comment: yes but not showing exception as i m using bootstrap theme.

Comment: So you better log errors somewhere to see what's going on

Comment: how? any idea? whether to use filing or something else

Comment: There are lots of logging libraries. I use log4net

Comment: ok i m trying to do so

Comment: I noticed in your query string that (based on the variable names) the Thumbnail_Path and Video_Path are switched around on the next line when you enter the values. It may not solve this issue in particular, but if the video path is trying to reference the wrong source, it could lead to problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the changes back to the source database. Right now it's only affecting the DB in the working directory

You can use Entity Framework to do this. Add a new item to the solution that is called "ADO.NET Entity Framework Data Model", you might need to install it from NuGet.

[image: Add Database]
[image: Entity Data Model]

I don't know how your folder structure is like, but you'll want a copy of the database in the project. Also change the database property 'Copy to Output Directory' to 'Copy if newer'. When you add the Data Model, it will go through a configuration.

[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2]
[image: Step 3]

After that there are only a few changes to make in the code..

```
try
{
    Database1Entities database1Entities = new Database1Entities();
    //Edit the connectionString

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(database1Entities.Database.Connection.ConnectionString);
    con.Open();

    //Changed values to be in correct order
    string q = "insert into videos(Upload_User, Title, Discription, Video_Time, Tags, [Format], Thumbnail_Path, Video_Path) " +
                        "values('" + user + "','" + Title.Text + "','" + DiscriptionTextBox.Text + "','" + time + "','" + TagsTextBox.Text + "','" + ext + "','" + thumbpathAccess + "','" + pathAccess + "')";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    //Save changes back to source
    database1Entities.SaveChanges();

    Response.Write("<script>alert('Data Saved!');</script>");
    con.Close();
}
```